# HTML - How do I make my SWF fullscreen?

Tags: html, apache-flex, fullscreen

I'm working on a project where I need to make a Flex application that fills the entire browser window (note that I mean that the toolbars should be visible and all that even if I say fullscreen).

To develop the SWF I'm using FlashDevelop (for the first time) and I'm stuck. When I build the project it displays no error and a file website.swf is generated. When I browse to this file with Firefox, it displays what I want and in fullscreen. However when I go to the generated index.html I get a white horizontal bar at the top of my screen (again the browser window).

I've looked around a bit on the internet and found several people suggesting that the CSS should include stuff like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { margin:0; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
    body { margin:0; height:100%; width:100%;}
</style>
```

But that didn't cut it for me, I still have the white bar. I've tried margin, top, width, height and border so far, nothing seems to work.

Other tutorials show how to make an SWF fullscreen as in the Firefox F11 equivalent, which is not what I want (and it still displays the annoying white bar when I press F11 :().

**EDIT**: Additionally when I place an extra line above the "altContent" div that says "Blub", this line will be displayed in the white bar.

For completeness, the HTML, since I expect this to be the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <script src="js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"Website"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF("Website.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin:0; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
        body { margin:0; height:100%; width:100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="altContent">
        <h1>Website</h1>
        <p>Alternative content</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img 
            src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" 
            alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to set padding to 0 as well?

Comment: Just did, didn't work :( Thanks for the suggesting though! Little extra info: If I add BLUB<br />BLUB<br />BLUB<br />BLUB<br />BLUB<br />BLUB<br />" between the <body>-tag and the <div id="altContent">-tag, the SWF shifts down.

Comment: And if you change `bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"` to `#FF0000` in `var params`, will the white bar above turn into red one?

Comment: Nope, when I change the color to red, the screen flashes briefly red before returning to the normal (greyish) background color. However, the white bar does not flash red.

Comment: If you use Firefox could you paste us content of the <body> tag as seen by Firebug plugin?

Comment: I'll try gertschi's suggestion first (see below) and come back with the results!

Comment: I am a Flex developer, I have one demo of full screen, check this to see if this is what you are looking for. In [this gallery](http://no-refresh.com/demo/PortfolioSlideshow/), look at the top right corner, there is one button for full screen (Sorry this gallery is not working fine) Then maybe I could help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML and CSS look fine. I've just tested it with Firefox 3.6 and Flash Player 10.1 as well as the latest version (2.2) of [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). The displayed SWF fills the browser window completly. There's no white bar on top of the SWF.

Try upgrading to the latest version of swfobject in case you are still using an older version.

BTW: You can remove the second line of your CSS. That's redundant.

Comment: I've tried this some time ago, but I think I screwed up my FlashDevelop installation... Since the project is cancelled it is very low on my todo-list as well...